# ksh/bash run command line from variable

Tags: linux, bash, ksh

I set in cmd variable the find syntax: , I use ksh shell/bash

```
 # cmd=" find /usr/cti/conf -name \"*.tgz*\" "
 # echo $cmd
   find /usr/cti/conf/ -name "*.tgz*"
```

so why when I want to run the cmd as the following I not actually activate the find ...

```
 # exec $cmd
  appserver1a:/var/tmp/    ROOT #     ( this exit from the shell )
```

it’s also  not works when I run with double brackets

```
  exec "$cmd"
  ksh:  find /usr/cti/conf/backup -name "*.tgz*" :  not found
```

what is the resolution for this?

Remark I not want to set the cmd like this ( this is works )

```
     cmd=`  find /usr/cti/conf/backup -name "*.tgz*"  `
```

or

```
      cmd=$( find /usr/cti/conf/backup -name "*.tgz*" )
```

Comment: What happens if just say: `$cmd` instead of `exec "$cmd"` ?

Comment: You can try `cmd=(find /usr/cti/conf/backup -name "*.tgz*")` then execute it as `${cmd[@]}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your command string in the variable:

```
cmd="find /usr/cti/conf/backup -name \"*.tgz*\""
```

Then, *evaluate* the variable contents:

```
eval "$cmd"
```

---

*UPDATE: the safer option, according to [alvits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3088572/alvits) and [Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3088572/alvits):*

```
cmd=(find /usr/cti/conf/backup -name "*.tgz*")
${cmd[@]}
```

Comment: Don't do this -- `eval` is an open invitation to subtle and incomprehensible bugs. Use an array (See @alvits' comment) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions - the one provided below and the one posted by Eugeniu Rosca - seem to work for me.

```
cmd="find /usr/cti/conf/backup -name \"*.tgz*\""
exec $cmd
```